# Handle JSON which sends array of items but sometimes empty string in case of 0 elements

Tags: json, gson

I have a JSON which sends array of element in normal cases but sends empty string `""` tag without array `[]` brackets in case of 0 elements.

How to handle this with Gson? I want to ignore the error and not cause `JSONParsingException`.

eg.

```
"types": [
        "Environment",
        "Management",
        "Computers"
      ],
```

sometimes it returns:

```
"types" : ""
```

Getting the following exception: `Expected BEGIN ARRAY but was string`

Comment: The first thing I'd do is track down whoever wrote the code generating that response and beat them about the head and shoulders with a wet noodle.

Comment: In JSON, an empty array is expressed as `[]`, not `""`. So as T.J. mentioned the author of this should probably be put on trial.

Comment: Yes I know the issue is with API, but I don't have control over response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have control over the input JSON string, you can test the content and decide what to do with it.

Here is an example of a working Java class:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    class Types {
        Object types;
    }

    public void test(String input) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Types types = gson.fromJson(input,Types.class);

        if(types.types instanceof ArrayList) {
            System.out.println("types is an ArrayList");
        } else if (types.types instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("types is an empty String");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "{\"types\": [\n" +
                "        \"Environment\",\n" +
                "        \"Management\",\n" +
                "        \"Computers\"\n" +
                "      ]}";
        String input2 = "{\"types\" : \"\"}";

        Test testing = new Test();
        testing.test(input2);  //change input2 to input
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a bad JSON schema is not under your control, you can implement a specific type adapter that would try to determine whether the given JSON document is fine for you and, if possible, make some transformations. I would recomment to use `@JsonAdapter` in order to specify improperly designed types (at least I hope the entire API is not improperly designed).

For example,

```java
final class Wrapper {

    @JsonAdapter(LenientListTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    final List<String> types = null;

}
```

where `LenientListTypeAdapterFactory` can be implemented as follows:

```java
final class LenientListTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // Gson can instantiate it itself, let it just do it    
    private LenientListTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // Obtaining the original list type adapter
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<List<?>> realListTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<List<?>>) gson.getAdapter(typeToken);
        // And wrap it up in the lenient JSON type adapter
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> castTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new LenientListTypeAdapter(realListTypeAdapter);
        return castTypeAdapter;
    }

    private static final class LenientListTypeAdapter
            extends TypeAdapter<List<?>> {

        private final TypeAdapter<List<?>> realListTypeAdapter;

        private LenientListTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<List<?>> realListTypeAdapter) {
            this.realListTypeAdapter = realListTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final List<?> value)
                throws IOException {
            realListTypeAdapter.write(out, value);
        }

        @Override
        public List<?> read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            // Check the next (effectively current) JSON token
            switch ( in.peek() ) {
            // If it's either `[...` or `null` -- we're supposing it's a "normal" list
            case BEGIN_ARRAY:
            case NULL:
                return realListTypeAdapter.read(in);
            // Is it a string?
            case STRING:
                // Skip the value entirely
                in.skipValue();
                // And return a new array list.
                // Note that you might return emptyList() but Gson uses mutable lists so we do either
                return new ArrayList<>();
            // Not anything known else?
            case END_ARRAY:
            case BEGIN_OBJECT:
            case END_OBJECT:
            case NAME:
            case NUMBER:
            case BOOLEAN:
            case END_DOCUMENT:
                // Something definitely unexpected
                throw new MalformedJsonException("Cannot parse " + in);
            default:
                // This would never happen unless Gson adds a new type token
                throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is it how it can be tested:

```java
for ( final String name : ImmutableList.of("3-elements.json", "0-elements.json") ) {
    try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43562427.class, name) ) {
        final Wrapper wrapper = gson.fromJson(reader, Wrapper.class);
        System.out.println(wrapper.types);
    }
}
```

Output:

> [Environment, Management, Computers]
>   []

If the entire API uses `""` for empty arrays, then you can drop the `@JsonAdapter` annotation and register the `LenientListTypeAdapterFactory` via `GsonBuilder`, but add the following lines to the `create` method in order not to break other type adapters:

```java
if ( !List.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
    // This tells Gson to try to pick up the next best-match type adapter
    return null;
}
...
```

There are a lot of weirdly designed JSON response choices, but this one hits the top #1 issue where nulls or empties are represented with `""`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.

The recommed way as mentioned in above answers would be to use TypeAdapters and ExclusionStrategy for GSON.

Here is a good example [Custom GSON desrialization](http://adavis.info/2014/10/android-custom-gson-deserialization-w.html)